# POST request returns 422 (unprocessable entity)

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have an AngularJS app that is using node.js and Loopbackjs to communicate with a mysql database. I am able to properly show my GET request on the `partial-home.html` aspect of the page, but when I create a new user it returns the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/se_users 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

Here is my code:

partial-create.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>Create a User</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form name="create" ng-submit="se_user()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user_id">ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.eid" placeholder="Enter EID">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="first_nm">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.first_nm" placeholder="Enter First Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="last_nm">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.last_nm" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email_adr">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email_adr" placeholder="Enter Item Type">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user_role">Role</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.role" placeholder="Enter Status Code">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user_active">Active</label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="Yes" ng-model="user.active" checked>Yes
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="No" ng-model="user.active">No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="mgr_full_nm">Manager Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.mgr_full_nm" placeholder="Enter Full Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="mgr_eid">Manager EID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control focus" ng-model="user.mgr_eid" placeholder="Enter Manager EID">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="insrt_dt">Insert Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="user.insrt_dt" placeholder="Enter Date">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="insrt_user_id">Insert User EID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.insrt_user_id" placeholder="Enter User EID">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="upd_dt">Update Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="user.upd_dt" placeholder="Enter Update User Date">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="upd_user_id">Update User EID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.upd_user_id" placeholder="Enter Update User EID">
                </div>


                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="addSe_user()">Create User</button>

                <br>
                <br>
                <pre>
        {{user | json}}
        </pre>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('userApp', ['ui.router', 'lbServices'])

.controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$state', 'Se_user', function ($scope, $state, Se_user) {
    $scope.users = [];

    function getSe_users() {
        Se_user
            .find()
            .$promise
            .then(function (results) {
                $scope.users = results;
            });
    }
    getSe_users();

    $scope.addSe_user = function () {
            Se_user
            .create($scope.user);
            alert('You have created a new user!')
            $scope.create.$setPristine();

        };

    $scope.editSe_user = function(user_id) {
        Se_user
            .editById(user_id)
            .$promise
            .then(function (user_id) {
                getSe_users();
        });
    };

    $scope.removeUser = function (item) {
        Se_user
            .deleteById(item)
            .$promise
            .then(function () {
                getSe_users();
            });
    };
}])

.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('');

    $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html',
            controller: 'UserController'
        })
        .state('create', {
            url: '/create',
            templateUrl: 'partial-create.html',
            controller: 'UserController'
        })
    .state('admin', {
        url: '/admin',
        templateUrl: 'partial-admin.html',
        contoller: 'UserController'
    })

}]);
```

Comment: You've posted a server-side error and you have only shown client-side code.  How can anyone point you in the right direction?

Comment: Good point.  My thinking though is the error lies in the syntax of my code either in my ng-model tags, ng-submit tag or in my .addSe_user structure.

Comment: Entirely possible, but you also didn't include the Se_user structure so once again, any answer would be solely guessing at the issue.

Comment: What can I provide to help you in diagnosing the issue.  Apologies for what may be a novice oversight, I am very new to AngularJS and really all of this entirely.

Comment: Look at the terminal that's running the api (`slc run` output) and trace the error back to the source (it should have spit out the stack trace). Or use Chrome Dev Tools to inspect the server response and find the API error and line where it breaks. My guess would be `$scope.user` has missing required fields.

Comment: @Brian the api isn't running via slc run but is being managed through Node.  I am executing 'node .' in the root directory of this project to fire up the Api (StrongLoop) at localhost:3000 and localhost:3000/explorer.  Upon further investigation of the error in the Chrome Dev tools, pin-pointing the exact error is difficult because doesn't present itself until after I click "Ok" to dismiss the alert that is found in the app.js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your create line from

```
Se_user
.create($scope.user);
```

to

```
Se_user
.create($scope.user, 
  function(newUser) {
    console.log(newUser);
    // only set pristine here, this
    // callback fires on success
    $scope.create.$setPristine();
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log(err); // will log the error to the console
  }

);
```

The alert shouldn't get in the way of seeing the dev tools output, but this structure makes it easier to get the error response by using the error callback in the call.

The way you have it, the alert that says you have created a new user will fire *immediately after* the ajax call to create the new user is *sent*—not received. There will be some delay for the server to respond so any code you write that depends on the new user being created (or erroring) needs to go inside the callback to the `.create()` method.

See the Loopback Angular $resource docs here: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK#AngularJSJavaScriptSDK-ModelresourceAPI

**UPDATE:** Chrome console - you should see a stack trace with your 422 error when you inspect the Network call in Chrome Dev tools, like this 401 error:

[image]

Please edit your original question and post the full text of that trace into it as a code block.

Comment: Hey Brian,

Thanks for the reply! I have adjusted my code accordingly and still see the same error as before.  Here is what the console.log returned on that error:

'Object {data: Object, status: 422, config: Object, statusText: "Unprocessable Entity"}config: Objectdata: Objectheaders: (name)status: 422statusText: "Unprocessable Entity"__proto__: Object'

Apologies that it is difficult to read

Comment: See update above - find the full text of the stack trace of the 422 error and paste it into your original question. Other things that might help - check the JSON structure of `$scope.user` and make sure it matches the structure of required fields as defined in `common/models/Se_user.json`. Paste both for reference if you can.

Comment: Hey @Brian!

Thank you so much! Upon looking at the stack  trace it pointed me to what was wrong and from that I was able to fix the form and it works!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the content type of the header:

```
header: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;application/json' }
```